# How to have regression lines in a different color brewer pallete than the points in my scatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, colorbrewer

Using GapMinder data, I've made the plot below with a different regression line by continent:

[image: scatter plot with regression lines]

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(gapminder_82, 
       aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F)
```

The problem is that the lines aren't really visible. So I'd like to use 2 different color palettes from color brewer. The *Pastel2* for the points, but I'd like to use "Dark2" for the lines. It would make the lines stand out.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filled point shape for the points, allowing you to use a fill scale for the points and colour for the lines:

```
ggplot(gapminder_82, 
       aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp)) + 
    # Make the edge color for the points totally transparent
    geom_point(aes(fill = continent), shape = 21, size = 3, colour = "#FFFFFF00") + 
    scale_x_log10() +
    geom_smooth(aes(color = continent), method = "lm", se = F) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
    theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if separate color palettes were possible, I think it would lead to confusion since you would be mapping the same variable to two different colours.

How about adjusting the alpha of the points to increase the visibility of the lines?

```
gapminder_82 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = continent), alpha = 0.1) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", 
                se = FALSE, 
                aes(color = continent)) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is simpler, and I really preferred it. I'm not marking it as accepted because the other one answered my specific question